# Joomla : Mambot

Tags: joomla-extensions

**Q1- Do some body knows what actually Mambot does in Joomla?**

**Q-2 Is there any Mambot for Joomla - 2.5.6?**

**Q-3 If Mambot is Suite of Administrator Modules, is there any other Extention which replace Mambot?**

I googled but very little found that Mambot is just like a **plugin**.

I also visited [Joomla Extensions - Joomla Official Website](http://extensions.joomla.org/) but surprised when saw that 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1- http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1893/251/ ::

> Mambots are essentially code snippets or mini-programs which, when
>   called via various parameters, either activate a program, a script, or
>   perform a specific function upon a Component or the database.

2-but as it seems that mambots are not like module or component in various type and etc, there are some mambot that have been created to control or access some commercial plug-in, component or whatever.

3- i am sorry, i don't have any idea about your third Q.
:)

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Mambots relate to Joomla 1.X only. They reflect the early versions roots in "Mambo". Mambots were small pieces of code inserted at a page level. They differ from modules in that they can't be allocated to specific menu items.

Q2. In later version of Joomla including 2.5, Mambots were replaced by "plugins".

Q3. Plugins replace mambots and you can publish/unpublish install and uninstall as many as you need for your purposes